# which jar libraries should i use when using json

Tags: java, json

im very new to json and i'm trying to run json with java. i found 2 json jar files from internet called

```
1)java-json.jar 
2)json-lib-2.4-jdk15.jar
```

if im gonna run a java code with using json do i need to include these 2 jar libraries or a single one is enough.
i included both libs and tried to run a code and i see this exception coming

```
NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang/exception/NestableRuntimeException
```

i realize this is beacause of a missing lib or something bt i dont know the jar files i should include when running a java code if its using json
can some one tell me every jar file i should use and my code is given below

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        json = new JSONObject();
        map = new HashMap<String, String>();

        map.put("name", "priyamal");
        map.put("age", "21");

        json.accumulateAll(obj.map);

        printJsonStrin(json.toString());

    }


    public static void printJsonStrin(String jsonstr){
        System.out.println(jsonstr);
    }
```

Comment: The missing class in the **NoClassDefFoundError** is located in commons-lang.jar.

Comment: whats the difference between 2 jar files i can create jsonobject from both

Comment: There's no difference between the two, but probably one or both of them has a dependency from commons-lang.jar, so you'll need that one as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The two most popular and fully-featured Java JSON libraries according to [Maven Repository](http://mvnrepository.com/open-source/json-libraries) are:

- [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson) (2.4)
- [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) (2.6)

and jars for both are accessible via Maven:

- Gson requires `gson-2.4.jar` (group id `com.google.code.gson`, artifact id `gson`
- Jackson requires `jackson-databind-2.6.2.jar` (group id `com.fasterxml.jackson.core`, artifact `jackson-databind`), as well as 2 supporting jars (`jackson-core` for streaming parser, `jackson-annotations` for annotation suport)

Jars that you listed are for other lesser commonly used packages (one for `json-lib`, http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/ is pretty old; other I don't even know what it is), so I would not recommend you use them.

Comment: thanks... i thought we shoulld use gson only if we want to create objects
and deserialize json strings to objects

Comment: GSON and Jackson allow multiple styles of usage, including use of "tree" style (nodes) and "untyped" (Maps, Lists) for reading, writing. So while most tutorials only show use of POJOs (which is usually the most convenient way to be honest), that's not the only way to use them. In your case, you can create your `Map`, and write it out to `OutputStream` or `Writer`; or, if for some reason it's needed as a String, that is also easy (for Jackson, `ObjectMapper.writeValueAsString(map);`)

Answer (score 3):

The missing class in the **NoClassDefFoundError** is located in **commons-lang.jar** from apache.

It can be downloaded [here](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/download_lang.cgi).

Answer (score 0):

Works as Java8:

---

Here is the link for [JAR](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=javax/json/javax.json-api/1.0/javax.json-api-1.0.jar)

For more help visit https://javaee.github.io/jsonp/

Download it and directly add in your Project.